# Explain <-(chan string)(nil)

Tags: go

I found [this `<-(chan string)(nil)`](https://github.com/yyyar/gobetween/blob/master/src/main.go#L79) strange construct in the [Gobetween](http://gobetween.io/) sources.

- Is it just a fancy way to block forever or it has some kind of advantage over `select{}`?
- <s>How to parse this statement?</s>

Answer (score 3):

The statement casts `nil` as type `chan string`, then reads from it.

According to [Dave Cheney's Channel Axioms](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/03/19/channel-axioms):

`A receive from a nil channel blocks forever`